# Как узнать количество дочерних элементов в иерархическом запросе Oracle

Tags: oracle

Есть таблица подразделений, которая представляет собой иерархический справочник с неограниченной вложенностью:

```
create table SP_HEADQUARTERS
(
  id        NUMBER not null,
  parent_id NUMBER,
  name      VARCHAR2(30)
)
```

где paremt_id ссылается на id из той же таблицы.

Есть также таблица Штатных единиц

```
create table SP_UNITS
(
  id             NUMBER not null,
  headquarter_id NUMBER not null,
name varchar(2)
)
```

связанная с таблицей sp_headquarters по SP_UNITS.headquarter_id = SP_HEADQUARTERS.id

```
alter table SP_UNITS
  add constraint FK_SP_UNITS_HEADQUARTER_ID foreign key (HEADQUARTER_ID)
  references SP_HEADQUARTERS (ID);
```

Нужно сделать вот что:
Построить запрос, отображающий дерево подразделений со всеми подчиненными узлами начиная с заданного идентификатора.  Для каждого подразделения отобразить количество подчиненных подразделений и количество штатных единиц.

на данный момент у меня есть запрос, который отображает "дерево" подразделений, а также количество подчиненных подразделений. Но не могу "прикрутить" к нему и количество штатных единиц.

```
select 
   the_root, 
   the_description,
   count(*) - 1                     as subnodes
from 
(
   select 
      connect_by_root a.id            as the_root,
      connect_by_root a.name          as the_description,
      id                              as id_head,
      name
   from 
      sp_headquarters a
   connect by prior id = parent_id
) 
group by 
   the_root, 
   the_description
order by the_root asc;
```

Также есть запрос, который показывает только дерево в "прекрасном" виде:

```
SELECT lpad(' ', 7*level)||name as Tree, id, parent_id
FROM sp_headquarters
START WITH parent_id is null
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY name;
```

Но мне нужно чтобы было вот так:

```
Подразделение           Дочерние         Штатные единицы
=====                   ===========      =============
Ташкент                 8                10
Карачи                  2                0       
Дели                    0                0
Пхукет                  0                0
Бомбеи                  2                0
Лаос                    0                0
Джанго                  0                0
Стамбул                 1                0
Ливан                   0                10




   insert into sp_headquarters (id, parent_id, name) values (1, null, 'Ташкент' );
insert into sp_headquarters (id, parent_id, name) values (2, 1, 'Карачи'  );
insert into sp_headquarters (id, parent_id, name) values (3, 2, 'Дели' );
insert into sp_headquarters (id, parent_id, name) values (4, 2, 'Пхукет' );
insert into sp_headquarters (id, parent_id, name) values (5, 1, 'Бомбеи' );
insert into sp_headquarters (id, parent_id, name) values (6, 5, 'Лаос' );
insert into sp_headquarters (id, parent_id, name) values (7, 5, 'Джанго' );
insert into sp_headquarters (id, parent_id, name) values (8, 1, 'Стамбул' );
insert into sp_headquarters (id, parent_id, name) values (9, 8, 'Ливан' );
```

Comment: Вы забыли указать, как именно, по какому полю, связаны таблицы SP_HEADQUARTERS и SP_UNITS.

Comment: указал теперь   .

Comment: на вскидку - сделать left join второй таблицы, кол-во дочерних будет `count(distinct sp_headquarters.id)-1` а кол-во штатных что то вроде `sum(decode(connect_by_root(a.id),a.id,0,sign(sp_units.id))`. Если не получится, через час время будет посмотрю детальнее

Comment: Кстати, не ясно штатные единицы считать по данному id или сумму по дочерним элементам, комент написанный выше рассчитан на сумму по дочерним. И на сколько много записей в таблице и какой ее % предполагается получать по условию "_начиная с заданного идентификатора_". Если записей не особо много или выбирается большая часть таблицы - то можно оставить как сейчас и условие с какого начинать накладывать на внешнем слое запроса по the_root. А вот если таблицы очень большая и выбирается лишь маленький кусочек это может быть слишком медленным и запрос придется строить совсем по другому

Answer (score 1):

```
select lpad(' ', 7 * level) || name as Headquarters,
       (select count(1)
          from sp_headquarters a
         start with a.parent_id=X.id
       connect by prior id = parent_id
       ) as childs_count,
       (select count(1)
          from sp_units b
         where b.headquarter_id=X.id
       ) as units_count
  from sp_headquarters X
 start with parent_id is null
connect by prior X.id = X.parent_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY name
```

Решил выбирать количества подзапросами. Если запрос используется для получения отдельных ветвей, а не всей таблицы, такой подход должен быть более быстрым. В случае же выборки всей таблицы возможно было бы лучше вынести как минимум получение units_count в отдельный подзапрос в from.

Answer (score 0):

в общем, получилось примерно такой запрос. немного громоздкий, но в условиях таких суровых требований что вы хотели??))

```
select lpad(' ', 7 * level) || name as Headquarters,
       b.childs_count,
       c.units_count
  from sp_headquarters a
  left join (select root_id, count(*) - 1 as childs_count
               from (select connect_by_root(a.id) as root_id
                       from sp_headquarters a
                     connect by prior id = parent_id)
              group by root_id) b
    on b.root_id = a.id

  left join (select a.id unit_count_id, nvl(x.cnt, 0) units_count
               from sp_headquarters a
               left join (select a.id, count(*) cnt
                           from sp_headquarters a, sp_units b
                          where a.id = b.headquarter_id
                          group by a.id) x
                 on a.id = x.id) c
    on c.unit_count_id = a.id

 start with parent_id is null
connect by prior a.id = a.parent_id
```

Comment: примем что, штатные единицы будем считать по данному id, а не сумму по всем дочерним. Исходя из этого,, какие можно делать "упрощения" и "ускорения"?

Comment: Вообще, таблица sp_headquarters может иметь неограниченное число вложенности. То есть дочернее подразделение может находится очень далеко от корневого (в данном случае это Ташкент с id = null). А "начиная с заданного идентификатора" в моем ответе считается та строчка, в которой написано "start with parent_id is null". ВМесто Null будет подставляться id подразделения, от которого будет все считаться

Comment: Начал смотреть детально ... второй connect by пока кажется нужным. Что самое печальное, тот что внутри будет собирать данные вообще по всей таблице исходя их каждой записи как из корня (собственно он для этого и нужен) на большой таблице это будет очень медленно. В общем буду думать, потом напишу, если что то действительно интересное придумаю

Comment: если честно, прям очень-очень честно, то я вообще мало что понимаю, что в этих запросах происходит)) тот итговый, который я представил мне удалось собрать из трех или четырех запросов. не знаю как он работает, просто в какой-то момент получилось то, что мне нужно) а то, что ты написал, тут вообще хрен пойми) но все равно спасибо. Если есть еще какие варианты, скинь,  с удовольствием ознакомлюсь)